# How to simply print a fetched JSON data on display in Lua? (to do so, write an existing PHP code in Lua)

Tags: php, json, api, lua

In **Lua**, I would like to **print JSON API data on a display of a device (Android smart phone)** (eg data is http://biocache.ala.org.au/ws/occurrences/search?q=Banksia%20Serrata). I believe I should use the following pieces, but not sure how to do it properly. Can somebody help me quickly?

```
local json = require( "json" )
network.request(url,"POST",listener,postData)
```

**If you know PHP**, it may be easier to understand my question. I have the following simple PHP code to fetch data via API and print it. And, I would like to do the same thing in Lua.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("http://biocache.ala.org.au/ws/occurrences/search?q=Banksia%20Serrata", "r");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);
$jsoncont = json_decode($contents);
//print_r($jsoncont);
print "<h2>Results"</h2>";
foreach($jsoncont->occurrences as $occ) {
    print $occ->uuid."<br />";
}
?>
```

Many thanks!

PS It is highly appreciated if you can show me an example for both POST and GET, if there is a big difference.

Comment: Can somebody help me is not a valid question. Please add more detail. What do you want to know? What do you mean with display JSON data? How to print it to console?

Comment: Sorry if it was not explicit. Yes, I would like to print the data (text) on the display. PHP code above does that. If the data is too long to display, it is easy to select a part of it, so I just would like to see any text printed on display. Then, I can work on doing more from that point on. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not easy for a beginner like me, but I manage to solve the problem by myself! Here is the humble code if somebody would have wondered and like to use it. Thanks @Piglet anyway!

If somebody can improve/simplify it etc, it is also highly appreciated.

```
local json = require( "json" )
local function networkListener( event )
    local res = json.prettify( event.response )
    local decoded = json.decode( res )  
    if ( event.isError ) then
        print( "--Network error-- ", ( res ) )
    else
        print( "Response: " .. ( res ) )
        local item1 = decoded.pageSize
        local item2 = decoded.totalRecords
        print(item1)
        print(item2)

        local myText = display.newText(item1, 30, 10, native.systemFont, 16 )
        myText:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 )
        local myText = display.newText(item2, 30, 40, native.systemFont, 16 )
        myText:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 )
    end
end

local headers = {}
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
local body = ""
local params = {}
params.headers = headers

params.body = body
network.request("http://biocache.ala.org.au/ws/occurrences/search?q=Banksia%20Serrata", "GET", networkListener, params)
```